# gmail does not show messages in outlook -- install as imap?

Tags: gmail, outlook, imap, 2-step-verification

I have a OnePLus 7 (not Pro) and use the Outlook app for certain reasons (work).

Because I don't want multiple mail programs if I can avoid it, I always had my Gmail account in there which always worked fine. But now, not sure if this is an update, my Gmail account has become unresponsive. If I delete the account and then:

1. add it via "Add mail account" -> add Google account, it asks for some permissions the Google way and does not complain, but it does no show any emails, not even the unread ones. I'm "done for the day".
2. add it via IMAP (selecting *not* Google) after setting "IMAP enabled" in my Gmail account on the browser, using [these directions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229), it says: `Log-in error` `Please check your email and password and try again.`

For route 2 I'm sure the problem is not the e-mail or password, because those work in the browser. And route 1 does not seem to work as it does not load messages.

Does anyone know how to access Gmail as IMAP on and Android device? Does it require the 2-step verification somewhere?

Comment: Note that Outlook app is not a mail client. It is a viewer of the mail store in Microsoft cloud (where all the credentials are stored). So the app does not access GMail at all, only the cloud servers do (so behavior can change without app update). Have you set-up an application password on the Google account? Because otherwise Google's two-factor authentication may be a problem.

Comment: I have two exchange e-mail accounts in there, and it has an option to add e-mail accounts, pre-configured ones from Gmail, Yahoo etc as well as costom IMAP and POP accounts -- I think it supports e-mail? I used to be able to read my Gmail in there without problems.

Comment: I just want to point out that Outlook is not a "classic" email app, it does not read any mail accounts, Instead the mail accounts are managed in Microsoft cloud where also your account data is saved. So Microsoft has access to all your mail accounts, downloads their mails to their cloud and then displays them in the Outlook app.

Comment: Ah right. So the IMAP options etc that I fill in are sent to the cloud, then handled there, then sent back to my phone, instead of from my phone straight to the IMAP server? Still, if the options are all correct that should also work (unless they specify that it doesn't)?